# DataGridView Column format as "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm tt" does not sort correctly

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I got a DataGridView with two columns.  The first column is Name and the second column is Datetime.  I load the Grid from a text file e.g. Mini Me|2020-06-01 3:22 PM
please see the code below. The Grid loads OK but it doesn't seem to sort correctly. Please see image of the first two rows sorted by descending. Could someone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd h:mm tt";

        while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            string[] values = newline.Split('|');
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    DateTime thisDT = DateTime.Parse(values[i]);
                    dr[i] = thisDT;
                }
                else
                    dr[i] = values[i];

        dt.Rows.Add (dr);
        }
```

[Grid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa4np.png)

Comment: Please use the debugger to inspect every line of your code. Then you might see how your code doesn't remotely sort anything.

Comment: @TheDueWithHat The DataGridView do the sorting not the code

Comment: ohhh, you mean when you click on the column-header

Comment: @TheDueWithHat Yes

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned the DateTime format "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm tt" in the title, but in the code you mention the format "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd hh:mm tt".

The image you show looks like the output of when you have used a single h in the DateTime format. Remember that once you mention this format, the values of DateTime.ToString(format) would be compared.

With a single h, 8:45 comes after 10:12, and hence first in descending order.
If you use the hh format instead, 08:45 would come before 10:12, and so, second in descending order.

Comment: so the AM/PM doesn't effect the sorting?

Comment: it does. use HH instead of hh.
HH gives you the 24-hour format.

Comment: if you are going to perform string comparisons on DateTime values, it would make more sense to use the standard "o" format instead of a custom format -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip